# Indexing PHP multilevel array by an Index

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a multidimensional array (set of rows from database), and I'd like to create an exactly same array, except the keys would be one of the items from the array.

For example, if I had:

```
array(
[1] => array("x" => "aa", "y" => 12, "z" => "more data...", ...),
[2] => array("x" => "bb", "y" => 13, "z" => "more data...", ...),
[3] => array("x" => "cc", "y" => 14, "z" => "more data...", ...),
[4] => array("x" => "dd", "y" => 15, "z" => "more data...", ...),
[5] => array("x" => "ee", "y" => 16, "z" => "more data...", ...).
...
)
```

and I called something like reindex(myarray, "x"), it would come back as:

```
array(
["aa"] => array("x" => "aa", "y" => 12, "z" => "more data...", ...),
["bb"] => array("x" => "bb", "y" => 13, "z" => "more data...", ...),
["cc"] => array("x" => "cc", "y" => 14, "z" => "more data...", ...),
["dd"] => array("x" => "dd", "y" => 15, "z" => "more data...", ...),
["ee"] => array("x" => "ee", "y" => 16, "z" => "more data...", ...).
...
)
```

I had thought PHP supplied something like that, but all I found was array_column which returns just the values of the columns.

Any ideas on this?  Or do I just need to write my own function?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a relatively straight forward `for loop`, I would just bust that out.

Comment: `function reindex($arr, $idx) { $arr2 = array(); foreach($arr as $key=>$value) { $arr2[{$arr[{$idx}]}] = $value } return $arr2; }` ?

Comment: @RiverC -1. that's not a comment, that's an answer :P

Comment: Oh, but it's not an answer, he didn't ask for an implementation, but if there was an existing one, or would he have to write his own ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no existing function because it's trivial to implement this particular functionality with the function primitives that *are* available. It's not complex or common enough to warrant its own specialized function in the core.

```
array_combine(array_map(function (array $i) { return $i['x']; }, $array), $array)
```

Comment: I know I can easily write a for/each loop, but I was hoping that some of the primitives could do the heavy lifting. This works great if you are calculating the new key. I simplified it for my version where I just want to take an indexed value.

Comment: array_combine(array_column($array, 'x'), $array);